# Determine if projection of 3D point onto plane is within a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d

In 3D, given three points $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$ spanning a non-degenerate triangle $T$. How to determine if the projection of a point $P$ onto the plane of $T$ lies within $T$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is a slight extension of the question given here: [Check whether a point is within a 3D Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/check-whether-a-point-is-within-a-3d-triangle)

There is an elegant solution to this given by W. Heidrich, *Journal of Graphics, GPU, and Game Tools*,Volume 10, Issue 3, 2005.

Let $\vec{u}=P_2-P_1$, $\vec{v}=P_3-P_1$, $\vec{n}=\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$,
$\vec{w}=P-P_1$. We then have directly the barycentric coordinates of the projection $P'$ of $P$ onto $T$ as

- $\gamma=\left[(\vec{u}\times\vec{w})\cdot\vec{n}\right]/\vec{n}^2$
- $\beta=\left[(\vec{w}\times\vec{v})\cdot\vec{n}\right]/\vec{n}^2$
- $\alpha=1-\gamma-\beta$

The coordinates of the projected point is

- $P'=\alpha P_1+\beta P_2 +\gamma P_3$

The point $P'$ lies inside $T$ if

- $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$,
- $0\leq\beta\leq 1$, and
- $0\leq\gamma\leq 1$.

Comment: Are there any corner cases where this should fail? The paper doesn't say anything to it

Comment: Doesn't this only work if point P already lies on the plane created by the triangle [P1,P2,P3]?

Comment: @MasterHD The point is projected onto the plane, so it does not have to lie on the plane.

Comment: Quick question... in the equations for gamma and beta, what on earth is this "[" and this "]".

I imagine it must mean "signed magnitude" and explicitly not just magnitude (for the author would have written | or || , plus Craig's answer below codes it as such), but I can't find something online to confirm what [ and ] are meaning here.

Comment: @Xenial They are just the ordinary [grouping brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics)). Note that they are not necessary in this case.

Comment: What is $/\vec{n}^2$? The square root of n squared? What does it mean to square a vector in this context?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Håkon Hægland for asking and answering this question, and especially for providing the key information from the hard-to-obtain paper: Wolfgang Heidrich, 2005, *Computing the Barycentric Coordinates of a Projected Point*, Journal of Graphics Tools, pp 9-12, 10(3).

I was web searching for exactly this information. Among the top hits were a question on the gamedev.stackexchange.com site, and this one. After implementing the technique presented here by Håkon, I posted that code and a link to this question at the game dev site: [Easy way to project point onto triangle (or plane)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28781/easy-way-to-project-point-onto-triangle-or-plane/152476#152476). Later it occurred that the C++/Eigen implementation might be useful to readers of this question:

```
bool pointInTriangle(const Eigen::Vector3f& query_point,
                     const Eigen::Vector3f& triangle_vertex_0,
                     const Eigen::Vector3f& triangle_vertex_1,
                     const Eigen::Vector3f& triangle_vertex_2)
{
    // u=P2−P1
    Eigen::Vector3f u = triangle_vertex_1 - triangle_vertex_0;
    // v=P3−P1
    Eigen::Vector3f v = triangle_vertex_2 - triangle_vertex_0;
    // n=u×v
    Eigen::Vector3f n = u.cross(v);
    // w=P−P1
    Eigen::Vector3f w = query_point - triangle_vertex_0;
    // Barycentric coordinates of the projection P′of P onto T:
    // γ=[(u×w)⋅n]/n²
    float gamma = u.cross(w).dot(n) / n.dot(n);
    // β=[(w×v)⋅n]/n²
    float beta = w.cross(v).dot(n) / n.dot(n);
    float alpha = 1 - gamma - beta;
    // The point P′ lies inside T if:
    return ((0 <= alpha) && (alpha <= 1) &&
            (0 <= beta)  && (beta  <= 1) &&
            (0 <= gamma) && (gamma <= 1));
}
```

Comment: This can be done more easily without cross products.  See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-barycentric-coordinates