# Operation on vector.

Tags: vector-spaces

i was working in 3d geometry and i looking for know, if a point belongs to a triangle.
I found this "[Determine if projection of 3D point onto plane is within a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544946/determine-if-projection-of-3d-point-onto-plane-is-within-a-triangle)" but i doesn't know how resolve this operation.
$$
γ=[(u⃗  × w⃗ )⋅n⃗ ]/n⃗ ²
$$
On google i found how resolve

- u × w

  - resulta.x = u.y*w.z-u.z*w.y;
  - resulta.y = u.z*w.x-u.x*w.z;
  - resulta.z = u.x*w.y-u.y*w.x;
- u . w

  - resulta = (u.x*w.x)+(u.y*w.y)+(u.z*w.z);

But how resolve this :
$$
[(u⃗  × w⃗ )⋅n⃗ ]/n⃗²
$$

Comment: The symbols are unintelligible on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these expressions that you copied (without great clarity), the "$n$" has an exponent of $2$ (one that's almost invisible on my system), so that it's 
$$
\gamma = [ (u \times w) \cdot n ] / n^2 .
$$

That's a little sloppy; by $n^2$, the author means $n \cdot n$, i.e., 
$n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2$.

A further hint: to make life easier for the folks answering your questions, spend a minute learning how to use LaTeX to format your mathematics.

Comment: thanks, this is my first question on Mathematics and i does know anything about Latex.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference