# Find closest point in triangle given barycentric coordinates outside

Tags: triangles, projective-geometry

Given a non-degenerate triangle ABC and an arbitrary point P in 3D space, I can project P onto the plane defined by ABC and check whether the triangle contains it as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544946/determine-if-projection-of-3d-point-onto-plane-is-within-a-triangle). I end up with barycentric coordinates of the point.

In case the point does not lie inside the triangle, i.e. any of alpha, beta or gamma are not in range [0..1], I now want to find the point inside the triangle which is closest to the projection of P onto the plane defined by ABC. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that 
$$
\begin{align}
P = \alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C &= \beta(B-A) + \gamma(C-A) + A\\
&= \alpha (A-B) + \gamma(C-B) + B \\
&= \alpha (A-C) + \beta(B-C) + C.
\end{align}
$$
We can classify the outside of the triangle in six regions:

1) $0\leq\beta$, $0\leq\gamma$, and $1\leq\beta+\gamma$, in which case the point is closest to $BC$. (In which case would it be closest to the $B$ or $C$?)

2) $0\leq\alpha$, $0\leq\gamma$, and $1\leq\alpha+\gamma$, in which case the point is closest to $AC$.

3) $0\leq\alpha$, $0\leq\beta$, and $1\leq\alpha+\beta$, in which case the point is closest to $AB$.

I'll let you work the other three cases which involve mixed signs, for example $1<\gamma$, $\beta<0$, for which the vertex $C$ is the closest point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the three checks above failed, and still one coefficient alpha/beta/gamma is greater than 1, P is closest to A/B/C respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: @Daerst yes. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks, I marked your answer as accepted. Unfortunately, I can't upvote because of my low reputation. I'll be back!

Comment: This does not work. The lines separating the 6 regions outside the triangle are each parallel to a triangle edge. However, the region closest to an edge is bounded by the edge and two perpendiculars emanating from the adjacent vertices. A nondegenerate triangle cannot have parallel edges, qed. As a concrete example, A=(0,0), B=(-1, epsilon), C=(1,epsilon). (Almost) every point with y > epsilon will be "closest to BC", yet there are many points which are closer to one of the vertices B or C.

Comment: @PaulDuBois I think your comment is correct, but it seems the proposed method is fine as long as you use a finite segment when finding the closest point on BC.

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulDuBois commented, the above answer (@hjhjhj57) is incorrect for obtuse angles.

In fact, we can classify the outside of the triangle in *three* regions:

1) $\alpha\geq 0$ and $\beta<0$, in which case $P$ is closest to either $AB$ or $AC$,

2) $\beta\geq 0$ and $\gamma<0$, in which case $P$ is closest to either $AB$ or $BC$,

3) $\gamma\geq 0$ and $\alpha<0$, in which case $P$ is closest to either $AC$ or $BC$.

The three regions are equivalent under substitution of variables and I will work out case 1:

If $\gamma<0$, and $(P-A)(B-A)>0$, $i.e.$ the projection of $P$ onto $AB$ where vector multiplication is the dot product, then $P$ is closest to $AB$ (verify that this can only be the case if $A$ is obtuse). Then
\begin{eqnarray}
  \beta'  &=& \text{min}(1, \frac{(P-A)(B-A)}{(B-A)(B-A)} ) \\
  \gamma' &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

Otherwise $P$ is closest to $AC$ with
\begin{eqnarray}
  \beta'  &=& 0 \\
  \gamma' &=& \text{min}(1, \text{max}(0, \frac{(P-A)(C-A)}{(C-A)(C-A)} ) )
\end{eqnarray}

And lastly
\begin{eqnarray}
  \alpha' &=& 1 - \beta' - \gamma' \\
  P'      &=& \alpha'A + \beta'B + \gamma'C
\end{eqnarray}