# Weighted average in 3D, with a triangle that has three z-coords of zero.

Tags: geometry

So, I'm following the Pixar tutorials on KhanAcademy, and thanks to that I'm now trying to make my own renderer. For this, I need to be able to determine whether a point I is inside, or outside a triangle in 3D space. I *will be* on the same plane as the triangle.

The way Pixar suggests using here, is weighted averages, which uses the formula: I = aA + bB + cC

With the three coordinates (Ix, Iy, Iz), it is possible to determine a, b and c, by solving the system of linear equations. When one or more of a, b, c is negative, I is outside of the triangle.

What I'm trying to do, is determining whether I is inside a triangle of which A, B and C have a Z-value of zero. Using the system of linear equations is not possible here.

How can I determine whether I is inside a triangle or not when all values of one axis are zero? I can just 'cut the axis off', but I was hoping there was a more easy way. I've taken a look at [Check whether a point is within a 3D Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/check-whether-a-point-is-within-a-3d-triangle), but I didn't quite understand the answers given.

Thank you very much for trying to help me out! :)

Comment: A t is missing in weigh(t)ed at your title. Please correct it.

Comment: Err thanks :) And done. :)

Comment: I derped there. Now it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way for 2D triangles.
Write a function LeftOf($x,y,z$), which returns True if $z$ is left of the directed line through $xy$, False otherwise.
Then $I$ in strictly inside $\triangle ABC$ if

> LeftOf($A,B,I$) and LeftOf($B,C,I$) and LeftOf($C,A,I$)

If you want to consider $I$ inside when on the boundary, adjust the definition
of LeftOf() to LeftOfOn() accordingly.

LeftOf() computes the [signed area of the triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html), and uses
the sign to return True or False.
You can find code for this all over the web, e.g., [here](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ftp.html).